# Actions with User-Generated Photos not showing up big

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo, facebook-opengraph, user-generated-content

We're using an open graph action to post photos made by our app. Even though we include:

`image[0][user_generated]=true`,

the image does not show up as a big photo in user timelines. It's merely in the recently activity box. The image is greater than 520x520px (as specified in [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/) document).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Photos marked as user_generated must have been taken by a user using a camera
As a developer, you must also request approval for using this Action Property in the DevApp as "User Generated Photos"

Comment: I haven't gotten approval yet -- but I am testing them as an app Administrator.

Comment: I tested it on a separate account that I added as an app developer -- and it worked. Could it be something about my account settings?

Comment: remove the app and re-add it see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

also possible with JSON:

```
{"recept":"http://my.recept.com","image:url":"http://my.recept.com/my-recept.png","image:user_generated":true}
```

as of now, approval is not needed for developer of the apps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also specify image[0][url]=url otherwise it won't show up